# Error in sample.int(x, size, replace, prob) size with R

Tags: r

The question is:

> Set the seed at 1. Take a random sample of size 25 from x.
> What is the sample average?

I tried this:

```
set.seed(1)
X = mean(sample(x, 25))
```

But got this:

```
Error in sample.int(x, size, replace, prob) : 
  cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'
```

What's wrong?

Edit: This didnt work either:

```
x <- sample(x, 25, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL)
```

Here is the intro:

```
library(downloader) 
url <- "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/genomicsclass/dagdata/master/inst/extdata/mice_pheno.csv"
filename <- basename(url)
download(url, destfile=filename)
dat <- read.csv(filename) 
dat <- na.omit( dat )

x <- filter(dat, Sex == "M" & Diet == "chow") %>% select(Bodyweight) %>% unlist
```

ERROR: Error in filter(dat, Sex == "M" & Diet == "chow") %>% select(Bodyweight) %>%  :
could not find function "%>%"

Comment: @NelsonGon I added an edit, it didn't work

Comment: You can check all the answers there or on the linked questions to that question.

Comment: It's hard to help without knowing what x is or how long it is, since that's what the error message says your issue is

Comment: @camille You're right... please look at the edit. I tried defining x, but get error.... Don't know how to define it

Comment: Now your error is because you most likely haven't loaded dplyr but are trying to call its functions (again, I'm guessing—there are other packages with `filter` and `select` functions). Before posting questions, I'd recommend reading your error messages closely and thinking about what they mean, as well as the documentation for the functions you're using, because they can be pretty informative